# How to find folder name by using file name batch

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make myself an automated Movie and TV shows torrent manager. My idea is to take the .torrent file name and to use it to find the downloaded Movie/TV show folder, which will be with the name of the .torrent file. After that depending on if folder name contains Series/S01.. etc to go to one directory (TV shows one) and if not to go to Movie directory.
For the moment I`m struggling to take correctly the filename and to use is as folder. (it is a test so the file is .txt instead of .torrent)

```
@echo off
:loop
set file=H:\Complete\*.txt
FOR %%i IN ("%file%") DO (
   set msg=%file%
   echo '%msg%'
   for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /a:d h:\Complete\%msg%\') do (
    robocopy "H:\\Complete\\%msg%" "H:\\Bash\\%msg%\\" /E 
      ping -n 2 localhost >nul
  )
)
ping -n 100 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

Please help with the current issue and if you have any suggestions for something else feel free to let me know.

Comment: It becomes a bit confusing with a long explanation, show the folder and file structure examples and the expected results. Give a minimal and complete example. Your question is not off topic, but it is a little unclear.

Comment: Don't use [tag:ping] to add delays to your script, use [tag:timeout] instead. Also where did you get the idea that double backslashes were used with [tag:robocopy]. Also the backslash is a directory separator, it is not a directory terminator so it should look like this `robocopy "H:\SourceDir" "H:\DestinationDir" /Options`, not this `robocopy "H:\SourceDir\" "H:\DestinationDir\" /Options`. Used like that your trailing backslash is escaping the doublequote, and `robocopy` would generate and show an error message ,as a result.

Comment: I`m sorry that it is not really clear what my question is. Basically how can I take name from file.torrent and match that name as a directory? In addition, the double backslash was a desperate try of making things work ( i just read it somewhere).